# NodeJS Error "Unexpected token"

Tags: sql, node.js, ubuntu, npm

I want create a website basic on Rullete. I got code and scripts. When i run Script i get this error.

```
[SyntaxError: Unexpected token <]
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Request._callback (/var/www/html/Bot/BOT/site.js:63:16)
    at Request.self.callback (/root/node_modules/request/request.js:200:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/request/request.js:1067:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:95:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/request/request.js:988:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:85:20)
```

I don't know how I can fix this. Can someone help me ?

Site.js

line 59-107

```
    load();

var prices;
request('http://backpack.tf/api/IGetMarketPrices/v1/?key=56fce4a5c4404545131c8fcf&compress=1&appid=730', function(error, response, body) {
    prices = JSON.parse(body);
    if(prices.response.success == 0) {
        logger.warn('Loaded fresh prices');
        if(fs.existsSync(__dirname + '/prices.txt')){
            prices = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/prices.txt'));
            logger.warn('Prices loaded from cache');
        } else {
            logger.error('No prices in cache');
            process.exit(0);
        }
    } else {
        fs.writeFileSync('prices.txt', body);
        logger.trace('New prices loaded');
    }
});

updateHash();
function updateHash() {
    query('SELECT * FROM `hash` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1', function(err, row) {
        if(err) {
            logger.error('Cant get the hash, stopping');
            logger.debug(err);
            process.exit(0);
            return;
        }
        if(row.length == 0) {
            logger.error('Wrong hash found, stopping');
            process.exit(0);
        } else {
            if(hash != row[0].hash) logger.warn('Loaded hash'+row[0].hash);
            hash = row[0].hash;
        }
    });
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var user = false;
    socket.on('hash', function(hash) {
        query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `hash` = '+pool.escape(hash), function(err, row) {
            if((err) || (!row.length)) return socket.disconnect();
            user = row[0];
            users[user.steamid] = {
                socket: socket.id,
                balance: parseInt(row[0].balance)
            }
```

Line 63 is it

```
prices = JSON.parse(body);
```

full file is here http://pastebin.com/yRELaZku

Comment: You need to post the code. Just showing us the error doesn't help. Give us all code around line 63 of your site.js file

Comment: Why you decided to tag this as PHP I have no idea :P

Comment: If we could see the code we could help you!

Comment: i add link to pastebin.

Comment: No, you added the URL as plain text. I fixed it. But it's better to include the code in your question.

Comment: I can add to this question but this code is too long :V

Comment: Then shorten it. Remove parts of your code until you have a shorter example that still produces the same problem. (In the course of doing that,  you might figure it out yourself.)

Comment: i change Prices to List and working. Thanks for help guys!;)

Comment: @PatrykKrawczyk let me answer your question, in below.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the body of the request is is not parsable json. Do a

```
console.log(body)
```

to check what data is being passed in

Answer (score 0):

Finally, you should change `Prices` to `list` or `Prices` to `dictionary`:

```
prices = [];
```

or

```
prices = {};
```